# How to open files in Intellij-IDEA with double click?

Tags: intellij-idea

My first day using this IDE...

is there a way to configure the IDE to open files in the project by double click? It is rather painful having to drag files from the project overview into the editor window.

Comment: You can disable `Autoscroll to Source`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can change the KeyMap.

Go to File->Settings and find the keymap section.

You will have to create a new KeyMap by clicking copy, and then look in the View section for "Jump to Source" and change/add the keymap you want.

However, as Bozhidar Batsov noted, double clicking may not always work so well.  Whether it works may vary by OS and/or windowing system.  I have no trouble with it in Mac OS X, but it doesn't seem to work well in openSUSE.

There are also other predefined keymaps that you can select from this settings screen.  They're set up to resemble other IDEs, so you might find them helpful if you're transitioning from something else.

Comment: Instead of "Jump to Source", peoplemight be interested to set up "Show Source".which allows to open a source file even if there are many objects inside.

Answer (score 7):

It is easy way to do in windows.

[image: You can do this way.]

Answer (score 3):

I found a [great solution](http://blog.orange11.nl/2008/10/13/descrease-the-double-click-speed-for-java-applications-on-ubuntu-linux/) to this problem by Jelmer Kuperus over at Orange11.

Create an .Xresources file in your home directory. Add the following line:

```
*multiClickTime: 400
```

Jelmer explains that this setting changes the default double-click speed from 200ms to 400ms, effectively slowing it down. Save the file and then run:

```
xrdb ~/.Xresources
```

The effect is immediate, no need to logout or reboot. Double-click in Intellij works as expected. I did try changing the mouse double-click speed in System Settings first before trying this out to see if that made a difference but it did not.

I am using Ubuntu 11.04, Intellij 10.5.2, and Sun JDK 1.6.0_26. YMMV

Comment: This worked for me. The problem was not with Intellij IDEA, it was the window manager not delivering double clicks to the application. I tried changing the keymap as in other answers, but I found that I could not get the double click mapped to any function.

Answer (score 2):

Use F4 to open quickly the selected files. Btw double clicking on files should work as well(at least in theory). Swing's buggy handling of such events, however, causes the double click to not always work in IDEA, so I eventually stopped double clicking and switched to using F4. You can also use "Autoscroll to source" from the projects menu - this will open the source files as soon as you select them in the project browser.